# Modifying the woocommerce search to search for product title's only

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Upon analyzing the searh through query monitor plugin, I can see that post_excerpt and post_content are also considered aswell as various statuses. See below query for full extract.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpio_posts.ID
FROM wpio_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wpio_posts.ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT object_id 
FROM wpio_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (6) ) )
AND (((wpio_posts.post_title LIKE '%iphone%')
OR (wpio_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%iphone%')
OR (wpio_posts.post_content LIKE '%iphone%'))) 
AND wpio_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (wpio_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wpio_posts.post_status = 'xlwctydisabled'
OR wpio_posts.post_status = 'open'
OR wpio_posts.post_status = 'closed'
OR wpio_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wpio_posts.ID
ORDER BY wpio_posts.post_title LIKE '%iphone%' DESC, wpio_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

There was a suggestion from an article (https://www.isitwp.com/limit-search-to-post-titles-only/) which involved adding this code in the theme's function.php file.

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;    
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

    $search =
    $searchand = '';

    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

After implementing this, i analyzed search again and it appears that it has no affect on search and query is still happening the same as before.